# SQL Query: Multiple parameters for 1 column

Tags: php, sql, database, filter, foreach

I have these database where I save some activities. This is how they relate with each other.

```
ACTIVITIES          WEEKDAYS           DAYPARTS

id                  id                 id
title               weekday            daypart
daypart_id
weekday_id
```

For a filter button, I want to filter the activities on weekdays. So for example, they click on monday, they get all the activities for monday.

The problem is that one column can get multiple parameters, so for example, they can click on monday, but they can also click on tuesday, and wednesday.. and so on.

I try to do that with this code:

```
public function selectAllActivities($dayparts = false, $weekdays = false){
    $sql = "SELECT `activities`.*, `dayparts`.`daypart`, `weekdays`.`weekday`
    FROM `activities`
    INNER JOIN `dayparts` ON `dayparts`.`id` = `activities`.`daypart_id`
    INNER JOIN `weekdays` ON `weekdays`.`id` = `activities`.`weekday_id`";

  if (!empty($dayparts)) {
  $placeHolders = [];        
  foreach ($dayparts as $key => $daypart) {
      $placeHolders[$key] = ':daypart_id'.$key;
  }
  $sql .= ' AND `daypart` IN ('.implode(', ',$placeHolders).')';
  }

  if (!empty($weekdays)) {
    $placeHolders = [];        
    foreach ($weekdays as $key => $weekday) {
        $placeHoldersB[$key] = ':weekday_id'.$key;
    }
    $sql .= ' AND `weekday` IN ('.implode(', ',$placeHoldersB).')';
    }

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

  if ($dayparts) {
    foreach ($dayparts as $key => $daypart) {
        $stmt->bindValue($placeHolders[$key], $daypart);
      }
  }
  if ($weekdays) {
    foreach ($weekdays as $key => $weekday) {
        $stmt->bindValue($placeHoldersB[$key], $weekday);
      }
  }
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
```

When I try to filter I get the following error:

```
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/INT2_DEV/dao/ActivityDAO.php on line 15
```

There is something wrong with the foreach funtion, but I dont really know what.

Comment: What is on line 15 of ActivityDAO.php seems to be wrong, and you are not showing what is there …., BTW, your sql statement seems to be missing a WHERE

Comment: foreach ($dayparts as $key => $daypart)  -> LINE 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...

This error is occurring because the variable that `foreach` is attempting to iterate over is not an array.

According to your logic, either `$dayparts` or `$weekdays` is not empty (i.e. `!empty($dayparts)` is true) and `$dayparts` is also true.

I would suggest using `is_array($x)` to test whether the variables are arrays prior to using them as such:

```
if (is_array($dayparts)) {
    ...
}
```